# How to undo "add to Git repository" after creating an Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, git

I created a simple Xcode project to try something out and accidentally forgot to disable the Git repository option.

Now Xcode is cluttered with source control things. How can I get rid of this afterwards other than copying all files by hand into a new Xcode project and making all project changes again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question, but if you just don't want the project to be a Git repository, you can simply delete the `.git` folder located in the project's root.

Comment: Can't see a .git folder there.

Comment: By default, the Mac OS X Finder won't list folders that start with a period.  You can see the .git folder from a Terminal by typing:

 ls -a

or run these commands:


defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder

Answer (score -1):

if you hasn't shared your commits with others yet, please use "git reset -mixed" or "git reset -hard" to set master to the last changes you want.

if you want to change index and working tree, use something like: git reset -hard HEAD^ 
if you want to change index only and keep your Xcode as uncommitted , use something like: git reset -mixed HEAD^

see man git reset